# android fatal error at - URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener

Tags: android, android-activity, android-configchanges

Coding android app registration module for the first time, getting a fatal error while running App after entering the mobile number during registration function & there is no request reaching to backend web-server -

Code is as below :

```
private void registerUser(final String name, final String MobileNo) {

        final String TAG = "MY_TAG";

       String tag_string_req = "req_register";
       StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {


              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                DialogOTP dialogOTP= new DialogOTP();
                dialogOTP.show(getFragmentManager(),"DialogOTP");


                    } else {

                          String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                  Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("MobileNo", MobileNo);
                 return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

wherein, AppConfig.java refers to the url for the backend .php code i.e. -

```
public class AppConfig {
    // Server user login url
    public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://testing.co.in/android/login.php";

    // Server user register url
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://testing.co.in/android/register.php";
```

- Register.php exists an the required url path

Can someone suggest how to make out the exact problem in syntax or what can be the root cause ?

Pls Find below the extact from LogCat  - 
11-22 20:24:01.690  18539-18539/com.android4dev.navigationview D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-22 20:24:01.690  18539-18539/com.android4dev.navigationview W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4156a930)
11-22 20:24:01.700  18539-18539/com.android4dev.navigationview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.abc.abc.activity.MobileVerification.registerUser(MobileVerification.java:243)
            at com.abc.abc.activity.MobileVerification.access$100(MobileVerification.java:36)
            at com.abc.abc.activity.MobileVerification$1.onClick(MobileVerification.java:92)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
            at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:139)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 20:24:01.790    2246-2344/? W/SignalStrength﹕ Size of signalstrength parcel:56

Comment: Please, attach a bigger portion of your code, so we can understand what are you doing (there is no call in that code, only declarations). Also try to explain with more detail the problem you have or attach a logcat. Please also try to improve the formatting and the grammar. Also review typos and avoid non proper English like `thru` and `&`. Think that the purpose is to let as much people as possible understand your question.

Comment: how can I attach a file here ? I want to attach a text file with Logcat dump.

Comment: jut copy/paste it as if it were code

Comment: Added the Logcat dump in above post...

Comment: Overcome the issue, I was missing the pointer to AppConroller.java in AndroidManifest.xml , i.e included "android:name=".app.AppController" under Application tag and issue got resolved.. Thanks